# Можно ли задавать вопросы с кодом и описанием контекста?

Tags: обсуждение

Можно ли на SO и SO на русском задавать вопросы так называемого широкого характер - т.е если вопрос сформулирован четко, но иногда выложить на SO на русском - не совсем получается - т.к. при четкой формулировке основной части вопроса все равно начинаются уточнения вида: "а что это за переменная, функция" - т.е от тебя все равно требуют контекста, что вполне логично.

Так вот, можно ли на SO на русском задавать такие вопросы - приводя код, и сразу описывая контекст этого кода если это необходимо? Не будет ли это расценено сообществом как "вот вам все детали проекта - пожалуйста сделайте за меня" ?

Comment: Перечитал вопрос несколько раз, и с трудом понимаю, о какой разновидности вопросов вы говорите. Точнее сказать, не понимаю. Но вам может быть интересна страница [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve).

Comment: в вопросе должно быть ровно столько кода сколько необходимо для воспроизведения проблемы в решении которой Вы хотите получить помощь

Answer (score 9):

Авторы вопросов вида "сделайте за меня" обычно НИКАКОГО кода не прикладывают, реже — приводят какой-то кусок кода, найденного в сети; часто такой код имеет крайне слабое отношение к вопросу.
Поэтому я бы сказал, что если вы будете приводить код — это как раз уменьшает вероятность "работы за отвечающего": оно по крайней мере показывает, что автор сам что-то пытается сделать.

Приводить код — очень желательно, это постоянно требуют в комментариях, есть даже в причинах закрытия такой пункт:

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?»)
>   должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и
>   минимальный код** для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. (выделено мной - А К)

Но [код лучше приводить МИНИМАЛЬНО необходимый для вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), потрудитесь убрать специфику, не относящуюся к вопросу. 
В случае когда специфики много — то вас будут спрашивать "а что у вас тут дебаггер показывает", дебаг в уме сложнее для человека.

Если у вас есть IDE и возможность посмотреть значения в ключевых точках — то у читающего вопрос такой возможности нет и приходится в голове держать возможные значения и проходить мысленно отладчиком ваш код строка за строкой.

А если вы будете отвечать на такие уточняющие вопросы через несколько часов — то нужно будет повторно начинать чтение кода.

Поэтому это в ваших же целях — убирать ненужные подробности.

Иногда бывает кидают код как есть, целиком, не понимая, где сбоит. И представьте себе — очень часто такие вопросы закрываются с лёту: человеку показывают, где ошибка, причём ошибка настолько пустяковая, что видно, что человек не потрудился даже убрать ненужные строки, иначе бы очень быстро локализовал проблемное место. На таких вопросах очень часто стоит причина закрытия "вызван опечаткой":

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или
>   опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте,
>   решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. **Обычно
>   можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием
>   минимальной программы** для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации
>   вопроса.

То есть нет никакой магии — если отвечающий методом пристального взгляда может локализовать проблемное место, то и вы, вооружённый IDE, всегда сможете сделать это весьма быстро.

В подобных случаях очень помогает [метод утёнка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) — просто попробуйте мысленно шаг за шагом объяснять воображаемому собеседнику, что вы делаете, какие шаги проходите и рано или поздно вы сможете находить проблемные места в коде.

Выше я процитировал две причины закрытия вопроса. В ОБЕИХ ПРИЧИНАХ есть фраза про минимальный пример и это неспроста. Поэтому я ещё раз рекомендую обратить внимание именно на этот раздел справочного раздела.