# Обоснование уместности вопроса на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, тематика, мета

Недавно на Мета сайте появился такой вопрос:

[Хочу проверить правильность своего краткого конспекта по определенному языку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9720/176217)

Я проголосовал за закрытие этого вопроса как "не по теме":

> **не по теме, потому что… Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится ни к обсуждению работы сайта Stack Overflow на русском, ни к программному обеспечению сети Stack Exchange, согласно правилам, описанным в справке.**

Однако к вопросу на текущий момент даны ответы уже от двух действующих модераторов. Это в свою очередь означает, что они сочли этот вопрос вполне уместным для Мета сайта. Мне хотелось бы понять причину такого решения.

Дополнительно можно заметить, что [в очереди на закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/682) модератор, давший один из ответов, последовательно проголосовал как "Оставить открытым". После чего вопрос исключился из очереди проверки.

Может бы я как-то ошибочно интерпретировал причину закрытия? Или онтопик для Меты должен быть расширен? Мне этот вопрос кажется возрождением [диалогов о работе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5812/176217). В текущем виде, по моему мнению, в вопросе нет чего бы то связанного с ruSO. Он мог бы быть уместным для [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), т.к. там является онтопиком выяснение места (сайта сети Stack Exchange), где именно стоит задать тот или иной вопрос. Но для русскоязычного сегмента SE, к сожалению, нет выделенного сайта для подобных вопросов. А значит, в текущих реалиях он должен быть закрыт.

Comment: См. также по теме [обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52437241#52437241)

Answer (score 4):

Если рассматривать вопрос без упоминания [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5), то это типичный оффтопик.

Я вот сейчас пересмотрел старые обсуждения. И, вроде как, тогда решили, что [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5) - это оффтопик. Если судить хотя бы по [этому ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4595/15479).

Так что, да, нужно закрыть.

P.S. немного странно, что один из модераторов, который проголосовал за "оставить открытым", в прошлом писал, что он [против таких вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5812/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment22175_5812) (¬‿¬ ).

> По сути: сайт — для вопросов о программировании. Мета — для вопросов о сайте. А чтобы поболтать есть чат.

Answer (score 3):

Если рассматривать вопрос без упоминания [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5), то это типичный онтопик.

Вопросы вида "можно ли спрашивать на ru so такую тему" -- это вполне на мой взгляд вопросы о сайте, а спрашивающий -- положительный участник, который старается уточнить подходит ли вопрос для сайта или нет.

- [Можно ли задавать вопросы типа "какую литературу почитать ... ?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8590/213987)
- [Можно ли задавать вопросы с кодом и описанием контекста?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5477/213987)
- [Можно ли задавать технические вопросы с юридической или финансовой составляющей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1234/213987)
- [Можно ли задавать вопросы в стиле "Плохой ли это код?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5375/213987)
- [Вопросы про софт: "что лучше"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/797/213987)
- [Можно ли на "StackOverflow на русском" просить обзоры (review) своего кода расположенного на GitHub?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6829/213987)
- [Допустима ли публикация решений задачек?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4838/213987)
- [Вопросы о data mining, machine learning, data science?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2237/213987)

То есть это вполне нормальные вопросы, которые раньше спрашивались и сейчас периодически возникают.

Я могу понять, если бы топикстартер выложил в вопрос свой конспект и отвечающие бросились давать ответы. Но нет: и топикстартер не ставил подобным образом вопрос и отвечающие указали "подобное для q&a не очень хорошо подходит, спрашивайте в чате".

Поэтому предлагаю считать данные вопросы "вопросами на онтопик/оффтопик" и оставлять. Я просто вполне могу представить ситуацию, когда кто-то придёт с аналогичным вопросом -- а у нас уже есть подобное обсуждение, можно сослаться на предыдущее обсуждение, а то и закрыть дубликатом. В случае же если подобные вопросы будут выпиливаться -- у нас придётся каждый раз заново объяснять и удалять, объяснять и удалять.

Comment: Вот только ответы в том вопросе не по теме от слова совсем. Там нет ответа на вопрос "можно ли спрашивать на ru so такую тему". Там ответы про конспекты...